# Bootstrap accordion starts collapsed, but if I expand it within ~1 second of page load, it will collapse itself again

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap accordion I have is working properly, and starts out with all panels collapsed, just like I want it to. The only issue occurs if the page loads and I immediately click to expand the panel (I'd say I probably have to click it within 1 second of page load). The panel will expand, and in less than a second it will collapse itself again. Any recommendations on how to resolve this issue, or even just suggestions for things to look into would be greatly appreciated.

```
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse"  data-parent="#accordion">
                            <h2 class="panel-title">
                                <h4>this is a title</h4>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                       //There's a bunch of stuff in this table
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: do you have any javascript in a document ready defined outside in your page?

Comment: I do have javascript, but nothing regarding this accordion. I see a lot of examples that are initializing their accordion with $('#accordion').accordion() but that is jquery accordion, not bootstrap accordion.

Comment: I think this is normal behaviour if you click the accordion before the site is loaded fully... you should probably do whatever is necessary to speed up loading, or hide the menus (display a loading screen) until everything is fully loaded...